# Tensorflow: lazily retrieve dataset per batch using for MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Disclaimer: In the past, I've predominantly used PyTorch, hence my reasoning is in accordance with how things are done in PyTorch as well.

I have a large database (MySQL) which I want to load as a dataset. It is not feasible to keep this dataset in memory at all times, hence it needs to be done lazily/on demand. My plan is to instantiate a `Dataset` object from the range of row id's, then retrieve the corresponding rows. This is much like how you would use file names/paths when using large files like images which you would then load that way. The issue with this method is that I can only retrieve one row per worker thread, meaning that I have to issue a `SELECT` query for each. I found that storing a batch in a table and issuing a `JOIN` as if it was a foreign key is orders of magnitude faster.

My first thought was to apply a `map` operation over each batch, which would require me to call a function of that kind after I obtain the batch from the dataset. In PyTorch, I would be able to define all this behaviour in a class that inherits from its `Dataset` class, which I think is a cleaner way to do it, and encapsulates this behaviour. Is there anyway to (neatly) do this within tensorflow?

Bonus points if someone can conjure up a method that is perfectly encapsulated (the user does not know how the dataset is internally stored and kept track of) from the user, yet conforms to the tensorflow API (i.e. a callable class to be used a generator for `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`).

Edit: In PyTorch, a common implementation is as follows (which I consider to be "neat" and is encapsulated).

```
class MyDataset(torch.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, row_ids):
        # Store row ids, do any pre-processing if necessary.

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        # From the item (may be several), join all corresponding
        # database rows and apply post-processing.
```

Comment: You may check [`tfds`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset), maybe there's some insight there, though I would not consider this "neat" tbh. Why not stay within PyTorch for this task?

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look! I use PyTorch for my studies, but my new employer requires me to work with tensorflow.

Comment: Please share a solution (or an overview) if you find "neat" one, would gladly read it, thanks.

Comment: Gladly, I added it as an edit at the bottom.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I've had a look at the link you sent, but from my understanding, this works to create a dataset as if you would reuse it. My dataset is an ever growing MySQL server that I am not allowed to publish and want to keep dynamic locally.